# Why doesn't a plane wave solution represent a single photon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Why doesn't a plane wave solution represent a single photon? And what is meant by the quantum-mean field being zero?

EDIT:

This post is an extension to a previous post I made asking about the photon in QFT.  I was asked by the person helping me to start a new question so he can respond in the form of an "answer" post and thereby keeping all "answers" on topic.  The link is here
[Quantum State of Photon Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234839/quantum-state-of-photon-question/234848?noredirect=1#comment512781_234848)

Comment: A plane wave solution *to what*? In *what context* is the mean of "the quantum field" (*which* quantum field?) said to be zero, and what do you not understand about it? C'mon, don't expect us to read your mind!

Comment: Sorry I should have prefaced this by saying that this post is an extension to my previous post asking about the photon in QFT.  I was asked to start a new question so as to keep all answers on topic as the person answering wanted to respond in the form of an "answer" post.

Here is the link.  
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234839/quantum-state-of-photon-question/234848?noredirect=1#comment512781_234848

Comment: Great. It will take some time to write it all down. In order for the question to be well received, as pointed out by ACuriousMind, you may want to slightly modify the text. You may write "... a plane wave classical solution to Maxwell's equation ..." and "Why is the quantum-mean of the electromagnetic field associated to a single photon zero?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so, let's start by defining the photon in the context of quantum theory. A photon is one of the quantum states of definite energy and momentum of the theory of Quantum Electrodynamics. In QED without fermions, a photon of momentum $k$ and spin $s$ is defined a the state

$$
|\gamma, \vec{k},s\rangle=a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)\,|0\rangle
$$
Where $a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)$ is the operator that appears in the Fourier-expansion of the electromagnetic four-potential operator $A^{\mu}(x)$:

$$
A^{\mu}(x)=\int\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k^{0}}}\ \sum_{s}\ \left\{e^{-ik_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ a(\vec{k},s)\ e^{\mu}(\vec{k},s)+e^{ik_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)\ e^{\mu\ *}(\vec{k},s)\right\}
$$
Depending on the conventions on the normalization of states, you may find different expressions for both the four-potential operator and the normalized state of the photon. In the conventions to which I'm used to, one usually writes
$$
|\gamma, \vec{k},s\rangle=\sqrt{2k^{0}}\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)\,|0\rangle
$$
Why it is so depends on the commutation relations between the operators of the theory. The quantization of the electromagnetic field is not an easy subject, so in order to get useful results we shall work under assumptions which would be theoretically justified if one started from the very beginning. First of all, let's assume that the $0$ component of the electromagnetic four-potential can be set to zero: $A^{0}=0$ (this is not the case in QED with fermions, but this assumption can be made in our case, by setting $e^{0}(\vec{k},s)=e^{0\ *}(\vec{k},s)=0$). Second of all, let's state without derivation that
$$
[a(\vec{k},s),a^{\dagger}(\vec{k}',s')]=(2\pi)^{3}\ \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')\ \delta_{ss'}
$$
$$
[a(\vec{k},s),a(\vec{k}',s')]=[a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s),a^{\dagger}(\vec{k}',s')]=0
$$
(again, the factor of $(2\pi)^{3}$ depends on the normalization conventions). This being said, you can measure the mean electromagnetic four-potential carried by a photon is the usual way:
$$
\langle A^{\mu}(x)\rangle_{\gamma,k,s}=\langle{\gamma,k,s}|A^{\mu}(x)|\gamma,k,s\rangle
$$
So let's calculate
$$
A^{\mu}(x)|\gamma,k,s\rangle=\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2p^{0}}}\ \sum_{\sigma}\ \left\{e^{-ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ a(\vec{p},\sigma)\ e^{\mu}(\vec{p},\sigma)+e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{p},\sigma)\ e^{\mu\ *}(\vec{p},\sigma)\right\}\sqrt{2k^{0}}\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)\,|0\rangle=e^{-ik_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ e^{\mu}(\vec{k},s)\ |0\rangle+\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\ \frac{1}{2p^{0}}\ \sum_{\sigma}\ e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ e^{\mu\ *}(\vec{p},\sigma)\ |(\gamma,p,\sigma),(\gamma,k,s)\rangle
$$
by using the commutation relations, where
$$
|(\gamma,p,\sigma),(\gamma,k,s)\rangle=\sqrt{2p^{0}}\sqrt{2k^{0}}\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{p},\sigma)\ a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},s)\ |0\rangle
$$
is a state containing *two* photons. This way, we find that
$$
\langle A^{\mu}(x)\rangle_{\gamma,k,s}=e^{-ik_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ e^{\mu}(\vec{k},s)\ \langle{\gamma,k,s}|0\rangle+\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\ \frac{1}{2p^{0}}\ \sum_{\sigma}\ e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\ e^{\mu\ *}(\vec{p},\sigma)\ \langle{\gamma,k,s}|(\gamma,p,\sigma),(\gamma,k,s)\rangle
$$
Now of course the inner product between states containing different numbers of photons is zero. So
$$
\langle A^{\mu}(x)\rangle_{\gamma,k,s}=0
$$
i.e. the mean four-potential carried by a photon is zero. As a consequence, the electric and magnetic field carried by a photon too must be zero (the derivatives can be brought out of and into the average sign). The direct calculation of the electromagnetic field-strength $F^{\mu\nu}$ is done as follows:
$$
\langle F^{\mu\nu}(x)\rangle_{\gamma,k,s}=\langle{\gamma,k,s}|\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}(x)-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}(x)|\gamma,k,s\rangle
$$
A direct computation shows that this indeed is zero.

So what does this mean? Does this mean that the photon carries zero electromagnetic field? Of course not. This only means that if you were able to measure the electromagnetic field carried by a photon many times, the point-by-point (i.e. separately in space and in time) average of the field would tend to zero in the limit of infinite measurements, and not because the photon is an oscillating wave: as I said, the average would be zero from point to point. On the other hand, a plane wave potential corresponds to a non-zero, fixed value of the electromagnetic field. Thus by no means you can identify it with a photon. On the other hand, complicated superpositions of states with different number of photons, from zero to infinity, can have non-zero average electromagnetic field. [This](http://motls.blogspot.it/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) article explains how one can get a specific classical field configuration from a superposition of photonic states.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this helps me tremendously! (Sorry for the late reply!) I very much appreciate you taking the time to write this up.

Comment: I will take some time tomorrow to read through the article you linked as I find this subject extremely fascinating.

Comment: Happy I was able to help :-D

Comment: Hello again!   This answer was so good and  I would like to put it in my doctoral dissertation and I need a source to cite.  Do you think you can provide me with a source that includes this derivation?

Comment: Not at the moment. I'll have a look at a couple textbooks and let you know asap.

Comment: I couldn't find anything much in line with what you need. I'm sure you'll be able to find some kind of bibliography on line. My main sources are Peskin/Schroeder, Weinberg (Vol. 1) and sometimes Landau (Vol. 4). They don't treat this specific subject for a number of reasons, which I feel I need to give you if you intend to make use of the answer in a doctoral dissertation.

Comment: First of all, the electromagnetic field is not free, i.e. you can't really treat  photons as non-interacting particles. In the real world, other fields exist as well (the electron field, the quark fields, the Higgs field, etc.) and they ALL interact with the electromagnetic field. This means that a realistic study of a phenomenon such as the electromagnetic radiation should take into account  those interactions.

Comment: In particular, what happens with a single photon in the way I defined it in the answer is that it is not an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian of the physical theory, which roughly means that all the physical quantities associated to the single-photon state will in fact change in time (something that doesn't happen in a free theory). A "true" photon in the physical theory is a superposition of infinitely many free states which comprehends, for example, states that represent electron-positron pairs, quark-antiquark pairs, etc..

Comment: As a matter of fact, the "true" states of the photons in the physical theory are not known: we do not have the full solution to the quantum field theory known as the Standard Model (neither we have that of pure Quantum Electrodynamics), thus no complete description of what is meant by a physical photon is known. Thus when presenting the picture of the photon as an eigenstate of a free quantum field theory, as I did in my answer, one should be careful: this picture is not a truly physical one.

Comment: The nearest one can get to the physical reality when treating particles as eigenstates of non-interacting theories is in the special case of scattering phenomena, which can be described by the so-called "asymptotic states" (Haag-Ruelle scattering theory). Scattering theory, though, is useful in Physics experiments, not in a coherent description of the world. Thus you may use my explanation as a toy model of the EM field, not as the true picture.

Comment: Standard textbooks on QFT are usually more concerned with scattering theory, the properties of particles and the general theoretical framework of QFT, rather than field-like properties. This is why it is not easy to find references on this specific subject. You may find something if you do some research on "coherence phenomena" in quantum theory (roughly speaking, how a classical field configuration is recovered from a quantum description of the system).

Comment: One last point: in my answer, I completely disregarded the subject of gauge freedom in the description of the electromagnetic field. This is a very important subject, even in the free theory: the potentials $A_{\mu}$, even as operators, must be subject to some constraint, such as $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}=0$ (Lorenz condition) or $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A}=0$ (Coulomb condition), which must be implemented in the theory in very specific ways in order for the quantum theory to make sense.

Comment: Again, my derivation is correct in principle (at least for free fields), but in order to make serious use of it one should be aware of each and every one of these matters, and much more: they are much more than technicalities; in fact, they lie at the core of the quantum theory itself. Other than that (and taken into account the gauge constraints - you MUST do that, I can't stress this enough!), what I wrote follows from basic definitions, so you should be able to report it by giving as a reference any introductory textbook on QFT.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments! They once again are excellent and help me a great deal in my understanding!  I will address all of these concerns in my final write up.  

My dissertation is on a subject called "The quantum radar cross section."  Essentially, it analyzes the scattering interaction between photons and the atoms in a target, and gives a representation of how "large" that object looks when viewing with a quantum radar.  This is directly analogous to the radar cross section in classical radar theory.

Comment: If you want to read up about it more, check out the book "Quantum Radar" by Marco Lanzagorta (whom I work with for my dissertation)

Comment: I will for shure! I wish you all the best with your thesis :-)

Comment: Hey, me again.  I started to write up this derivation and there is one thing I am not sure about.  I thought I understood it earlier but as I think about it, I am having doubts.  Can you explain this sentence more?
"On the other hand, a plane wave potential corresponds to a non-zero, fixed value of the electromagnetic field."
I read over your reply a bunch of times but I just don't get how an oscillating wave can have a non-zero mean value.    I must be missing something.

Comment: Sure. We can have this conversation by email, or Facebook, or whatever (too many comments are usually forbidden on SE). My email is giorgiocomitini@gmail.com, just write me there. (If giving away one's email is forbidden on SE I'm sorry in advance).